# Finding the First Few Terms of the Sum of Two Infinite Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Consider $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{j}d_{k}c_{j-k}a_{n-j}x^{n-11}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}e_{k}b_{n-k}x^{n-8}.$$

Given that I know the first few values of $d,c,a,e,b$, I am able to compute the first few terms for each of the series. However, I simply cannot add the terms (with same powers of $x$) from the two series and conclude that this sum represents the first few terms of the entire sum, namely, $f(x)$.

Is the following correct in terms of adding the two series?

Let $\alpha_{0}=\alpha_{1}=\alpha_{2}=0$ and $\alpha_{k}=1$, $k=3,4,\ldots$. Then,
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{j}d_{k}c_{j-k}a_{n-j}x^{n-11}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\alpha_{k}e_{k}b_{n-k}x^{n-11}$$

$$\Rightarrow\quad f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{j}d_{k}c_{j-k}a_{n-j}+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\alpha_{k}e_{k}b_{n-k}\right)x^{n-11}$$

> **Included Later**

The formula for $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}e_{k}b_{n-k}x^{n-8}$ while reducing $x^{n-8}$ to $x^{n-11}$ with the introduction of $\alpha_{k}$ is incorrect.

The correct form is $\displaystyle\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-3}e_{k}b_{n-3-k}x^{n-11}$, where the inside sum is $0$ whenever $n-3<k$. (I hope this is correct). But I think it still does not provide a way of writing $f(x)$ as a single sum.

> **Question**
>
> Suppose I want to write down the first 10 terms of $f(x)$. I can then write down the first 10 terms of the first sum and the first 7 terms of the second sum. Adding these two together will give me the first 10 terms of $f(x)$. Will this be correct?

Thanks, Radz.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that
$f(x) =
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( x^{n-11} \sum_{j=0}^n \left( a_{n-j} \sum_{k=0}^j d_k c_{j-k}
\right) \right) +
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( x^{n-8}  \sum_{j=0}^n  e_j b_{n-j}
\right) 
$ ?

Comment: Dear Reinderien, I initially had products of infinite series and used the Cauchy Product for simplification. For example, the 2nd sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}e_{k}b_{n-k}x^{n-8}$ was derived from $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}x^{n-3}\times\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e_{n}x^{n-5}$.

Comment: That makes sense, I think. Without more knowledge the most I know to simplify this is $f(x) =
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[ x^{n-11} \sum_{j=0}^n \left( a_{n-j} \sum_{k=0}^j d_k c_{j-k}
\right)  +
 x^{n-8}  \sum_{j=0}^n  e_j b_{n-j}
 \right]
$